# Update combo box value list based on other combo box selection

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have a table named Devices. Two of the fields in this table are Make and Model.

I'm creating a form to add new devices to the database.

I want the user to select the make and model data from combo boxes. For data integrity purposes, I want these to be limited to the existing make and model items already in the database (with the option to add a new make/model if needed).

The makeCombo is populated by a simple query (SELECT DISTINCT Devices.Make FROM Devices;), and it works.

I would like based on the selection of the make, the modelCombo update to the appropriate values (example: the user selects Dell as the make, and the modelCombo updates to contain all Dell models in the database, as well as allowing for a new model, in the event of a Dell device not currently in the database).

General format of the Devices table: DeviceID is the primary key, Make and Model are both fields in the Devices table.

I've used this type of VBA in the past for smaller tasks/databases, but this database has several hundred records, and it would take far too long to hard code each make/model combination.

```vb
Private Sub combo1_Change()
    If combo1 = "op1" Then
        Me.combo2.RowSourceType = "Value List"
        Me.combo2.RowSource = "a; b; c"
    Else
        Me.combo2.RowSourceType = "Value List"
        Me.combo2.RowSource = "default"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I find the answer minutes after posting....

```
Private Sub makeCombo_AfterUpdate()
'enables the modelCombo for data selection
modelCombo.Enabled = True
'updates the modelCombo to reflect the appropriate data in the makeCombo
modelCombo.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT Devices.Model FROM Devices WHERE Devices.Make = makeCombo.Value"
modelCombo.Requery

End Sub
```

Just did that, set the modelCombo row source type to Table/Query and it worked perfectly. Hopefully this helps someone else with the same problem!